# compling kernels for armhf

Tags: linux-kernel, arm

I am trying to compile my own kernel but I am having some issues with understanding.

I am using the latest kernel available from kernel.org.

My issue is at current: I have zero clue on what options I would need to ensure this kernel is correct for an armv7 (armhf) architecture. Does anyone have a list or a link to other sources which can aid me in the specific endeavour of compiling a kernel for arm7? Yes I have searched this previously but I have not found anything I think is of use. I am compiling this kernel on the same architecture I wish to run it on (if that is of any importance)

Comment: This may help: http://superuser.com/questions/287371/obtain-kernel-config-from-currently-running-linux-system

Answer (score 0):

You will automatically get a armv7hf kernel, if you compile it on a running armv7hf-machine. Try 
`file <kernel-binary>` 
this will tell you what type the kernel is.
The hard-fload (hf) thing is selected somewhere in "target architecture" subtree, if i remember that correctly.

Other than that you have the option of building your own toolchain on a host with different architecture (cross-compiling), and using the toolchain to create a kernel and applications for this target.

When you want to use option 2, you may want to have a look at "buildroot" or other embedded distros. Configure your kernel under buildroot, and build it. Be sure to select the correct compiler, and the correct target architecture you want to use.
After the build-process the output of the buildroot-process (under directory output/ or similar) holds the kernel, ramimmage, plus compilers and all binaries for the currently created kernel/abi.

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Usually the board/SoC manufacturer will distribute their own fork of the Linux source tree, containing necessary patches (e.g. for video acceleration). In other words, it's very unlikely that your vanilla kernel will boot on your device without modification. You may visit the manufacturer's wiki / forum site in order to get a link to the kernel sources and a short description explaining how to compile a custom kernel from source.

Examples:

http://odroid.com/dokuwiki/doku.php

http://wiki.solid-run.com/doku.php?id=products:imx6:software:development:kernel